# vue js - nested object as v-model not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, v-model

I am new to Vue JS. I facing one issue in one scenario.
I have below object

```
const testData = [ {
        "4948-8a16-5ab7f89553ab":[
                {
                    "App - App Development":"0.00: 0.00: 0.20" 
                },
                {   
                    "App - App Support & Operations":"0.00: 0.10: 0.20"
                },
                {
                    "Data Cent - Enterprise Data Cent":"0.00: 0.00: 0.15"
                },
                {
                    "Data Cent - Other":"0.10: 0.10: 0.20"
                }
           
        ]
    }]
```

I am looping through above object and binding it to dropdown as below

```
<template v-for="(element, index) in Object.entries(product[1][Object.keys(product[1])[0]])">
            
            <tr :key="Object.keys(product[1])[0] + '_' + 'C_' + index">
              <td><th class="group-name" colspan="4">Data : SubData</th></td>
              <td><dig-select
                  :options="someMap"
                  class="edit-styles-child"
                  v-model="Object.keys(element[1])[0]"></aig-select></td>
              <td>
            <tr></template>
```

Also, I am splitting "0.00: 0.00: 0.20" string from above object and binding it to textbox like below

```
<td><b-form-input
:type="'number'"
v-model="element[1][Object.keys(element[1])[0]].split(': ')[0]"
@change="fteChanged"/>
```

Everything is getting displayed correctly. But when I change the values from dropdown or modify input value, it is not reflecting updated value. Does v-model work in above scenario? or I have to do something extra?

Any help/pointers appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any solution for these issues?

Comment: i think it would work only with the <input/> tag as stated in the docs. [here](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind). they say that it is limited to 3 elements